# Switching from .net7.0-android to .net8.0-android causes 'missing java symbols errors' in runtime inside a .net8.0-android MAUI app

Tags: java, c#, .net, msbuild, dotnet-bindings

I have a .net7.0-android C# project/nuget which binds a certain underlying java (.aar) library and it works *flawlessly* when I load it in a .net8 (MAUI) android-app:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <IsOSX Condition="      '$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::OSX)))'     == 'true' ">true</IsOSX>
        <IsLinux Condition="    '$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Linux)))'   == 'true' ">true</IsLinux>
        <IsWindows Condition="  '$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::Windows)))' == 'true' ">true</IsWindows>
        <IsUnix Condition="     '$(IsOSX)' == 'true' OR '$(IsLinux)' == 'true' ">true</IsUnix>

        <TargetFramework>net7.0-android</TargetFramework>

        <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <IsBindingProject>true</IsBindingProject>

        <NoWarn>$(NoWarn);CS0108;CS0114;BG8700;BG8605;BG8606;NETSDK1202;</NoWarn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <AndroidLinkMode>Full</AndroidLinkMode>
        <AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;arm64-v8a</AndroidSupportedAbis>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <AndroidLibsFolder>Libraries</AndroidLibsFolder>
        <AndroidLibsDependenciesFolder>$(AndroidLibsFolder)/Dependencies</AndroidLibsDependenciesFolder>

        <CoreAarLibrary>$(AndroidLibsFolder)/mcumgr-wrapper.aar</CoreAarLibrary>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="Libraries\"/>
        <Folder Include="Libraries\Dependencies\" />
        <Folder Include="Transforms\"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="PrintBuildInfo" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
        <Message Importance="High" Text="OS:               '$(OS)'               "/>
        <Message Importance="High" Text="Platform:         '$(Platform)'         "/>
        <Message Importance="High" Text="PackageId:        '$(PackageId)'        "/>
        <Message Importance="High" Text="Configuration:    '$(Configuration)'    "/>
        <Message Importance="High" Text="PackageVersion:   '$(PackageVersion)'   "/>
        <Message Importance="High" Text="TargetFramework:  '$(TargetFramework)'  "/>
        <Message Importance="High" Text="DefineConstants:  '$(DefineConstants)'  "/>
        <Message Importance="high" Text="DesignTimeBuild:  '$(DesignTimeBuild)'  "/>
        <Message Importance="high" Text="BuildingProject:  '$(BuildingProject)'  "/>
        <Message Importance="high" Text="MSBuildNodeCount: '$(MSBuildNodeCount)' "/>

        <Message Importance="high" Text="ShouldBuildNativeLibraries: '$(ShouldBuildNativeLibraries)' "/>
    </Target>

    <Import Project="Foobar.Bindings.Android.NetX.targets"/>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- these dependencies have been field-tested and are known to work at least as far back as Android 10.0 -->
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.AndroidX.Core" Version="1.12.0.4" PrivateAssets="All" />

        <!-- the mcumgr-file-uploading aspect KotlinX.Coroutines jars with version 1.7+ -->
        <!-- to work as intended otherwise we get missing symbols errors in runtime     -->
        <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.KotlinX.Coroutines.Android" Version="1.8.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The file 'Foobar.Bindings.Android.NetX.targets' looks like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Project>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <LangVersion>10.0</LangVersion>

        <!-- net7 supports android13 and it corresponds to android-api level 33.0 -->
        <TargetPlatformVersion Condition="      '$(TargetFramework.ToLower().StartsWith(net7.0))' == 'true' ">33.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition=" '$(TargetFramework.ToLower().StartsWith(net7.0))' == 'true' ">33</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>

        <!-- net8 supports android13 and it corresponds to android-api level 34.0 -->
        <TargetPlatformVersion Condition="      '$(TargetFramework.ToLower().StartsWith(net8.0))' == 'true' ">34.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition=" '$(TargetFramework.ToLower().StartsWith(net8.0))' == 'true' ">34</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- the default mechanism automagically scans aars and jars and ... messes things up when multiple aar and jars are involved resulting in cryptic crashes  -->
        <!-- during the build process   so we reset everything back to a blank slate and then proceed to manually set up everything from scratch like we always do  -->
        <ReferenceJar Remove="**"/>
        <TransformFile Remove="**"/>
        <AndroidLibrary Remove="**"/>
        <AndroidAarLibrary Remove="**"/>

        <!-- and now we set everything properly ourselves ala net6+   salient points:                                  -->
        <!--                                                                                                           -->
        <!-- 1  DO NOT USE WILDCARDS FOR 'AndroidLibrary' BECAUSE WILDCARDS GET EVALUATED WHEN MSBUILD FIRST LOADS     -->
        <!--    CAUSING THE AZURE PIPELINES TO NOT MATCH ANYTHING AND THUS BREAK THE BUILD!                            -->
        <!--                                                                                                           -->
        <!--    SOLUTION: JUST USE FULLBLOWN EXPLICIT FILEPATHS INSTEAD                                                -->
        <!--                                                                                                           -->
        <!-- 2  we dont use AndroidAarLibrary at all because it turned out not to be irrelevant                        -->
        <!--                                                                                                           -->
        <!-- 3  also notice that we have intentionally omitted any and all kotlin libraries as these java-libs are     -->
        <!--    automatically included via implicitly referenced nugets (xamarin.kotlinx.*) brought in by the net6+    -->
        <!--    build system itself                                                                                    -->
        <!--                                                                                                           -->
        <!-- https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/blob/main/Documentation/guides/OneDotNetEmbeddedResources.md   -->
        <!--                                                                                                           -->
        <TransformFile Include="Transforms/*.xml"/>

        <AndroidLibrary Include="$(CoreAarLibrary)" Bind="true" Condition=" 'Exists($(CoreAarLibrary))' == 'true' " />
        
        <AndroidLibrary Include="$(AndroidLibsFolder)/Dependencies/slf4j-api.jar" Bind="false" />
        <AndroidLibrary Include="$(AndroidLibsFolder)/Dependencies/jackson-core.jar" Bind="false" />
        <AndroidLibrary Include="$(AndroidLibsFolder)/Dependencies/jackson-databind.jar" Bind="false" />
        <AndroidLibrary Include="$(AndroidLibsFolder)/Dependencies/jackson-annotations.jar" Bind="false" />
        <AndroidLibrary Include="$(AndroidLibsFolder)/Dependencies/jackson-dataformat-cbor.jar" Bind="false" />
        <AndroidLibrary Include="$(AndroidLibsFolder)/Dependencies/nordicsemi-android-ble-2.7.3.jar" Bind="false" />
        <AndroidLibrary Include="$(AndroidLibsFolder)/Dependencies/nordicsemi-android-mcumgr-ble-1.9.2.jar" Bind="false" />
        <AndroidLibrary Include="$(AndroidLibsFolder)/Dependencies/nordicsemi-android-mcumgr-core-1.9.2.jar" Bind="false" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="PrintBindingConfiguration" AfterTargets="CoreCompile">
        <Message Importance="High" Text="**** Transform files to use for NetX-Android (@(TransformFile->Count()) in total):      " />
        <Message Importance="high" Text="****                                                                                    " />
        <Message Importance="high" Text="****   '%(TransformFile.Identity)'                                                      " />
        <Message Importance="high" Text="****                                                                                    " />
        
        <Message Importance="High" Text="**** Android libraries to embed for NetX-Android (@(AndroidLibrary->Count()) in total): " />
        <Message Importance="high" Text="****                                                                                    " />
        <Message Importance="high" Text="****   '%(AndroidLibrary.Identity)'                                                     " />
        <Message Importance="high" Text="****                                                                                    " />

        <Error Text="No transform files found on disk! This looks fishy ... erroring out ..."
               Condition=" @(TransformFile->Count()) == 0 "/>
        
        <ItemGroup>
            <MissingTransformFiles Include="@(TransformFile)" Condition="    ! Exists(%(FullPath)) " />
            <MissingAndroidLibraries Include="@(AndroidLibrary)" Condition=" ! Exists(%(FullPath)) " />
        </ItemGroup>

        <Error Text="@(MissingTransformFiles->Count()) file(s) specified by the property 'TransformFile' were not found on disk: $(MissingTransformFiles)"
               Condition=" @(MissingTransformFiles->Count()) != 0 "/>

        <Error Text="@(MissingAndroidLibraries->Count()) file(s) specified by the property 'AndroidLibrary' were not found on disk: $(MissingAndroidLibraries)"
               Condition=" @(MissingAndroidLibraries->Count()) != 0 "/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

But when I switch over from net7 to net8 I run into issues in runtime: The nugets are generated but when the .net8.0 MAUI app attempts to call the C# bindings to java
I get errors about 'missing java symbols' in 'nordicsemi-android-mcumgr-ble-1.9.2.jar' which is completely absurd considering that the exact same nuget works perfectly
if I compile it targetting .net7.

Did something change in the way java libraries get bound in .net8? What gives?

PS: I use the latest .net8.0 workloads at the time of this writing